# Cannot Successfully Instantiate Huawei Camera Engine (Cloud Debugging)

Tags: android, kotlin, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I have to use the Huawei Camera Engine for a project and -- funnily enough -- have trouble instantiating the CameraKit. I followed the official documentation and instantiated it by using:

```
private var cameraKit: CameraKit? = null
...
cameraKit = CameraKit.getInstance(applicationContext)
```

For debugging, I'm using Huawei's official Cloud Debugging option in the App Gallery and the Mate 30. Looking at the logs, however, `cameraKit` is always `null`.

Has anyone ever had this problem? I'm guessing it is either `null` because you cannot use the CameraKit + Cloud Debugging or because there are some extra settings you have to enable in the App Gallery!?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to their own statements on the official website for the Camera Engine SDK:
[image]

Cloud Debugging + Camera Engine does not work for the Mate 30, but it works fine with the P40 (although not in the official list).

Comment: Would you please provide your log files so we can investigate this issue internally? thanks